# How should I go about testing first solution strategies?

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am trying to solve a large vehicle routing problem with many pickup and delivery constraints and time windows and demands. There are so many first search strategies and I am a novice user that does not know which one to try first and how to set it up. Is there a brute force solve method that tries one solver after the other? Which first solution strategies should I definitely try?

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it was one by one and checked the answers, there are not that many first solution strategy. "PathCheapestArc works the best based on my experience.

Comment: in terms of performance (running time) or in terms of finding a solution? I am currently running a for loop over all options in https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/routing_options

Comment: I looked at my results again, "Global Cheapest Arc" and "Local Cheapest Arc" as First solution strategy, combined with "Guided Local search" as Local Search Option for 30 sec gives the best result in terms of total travel time.
Even without local search option, these two had the best result in terms of total travel time.